# Pass the return value of a function to directive - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, directive

Let's say I have a directive `myDirective`. That directive wants to have an array of tag names `tags`, like for example `['new', 'owner']`. This array is generated on the fly like;

```
<my-directive ng-repeat="that in a" tags="getTags(that.id)"></my-directive>

angular.module('x').directive(...
  scope: {
   tags: '@'
  }
};
```

Where `getTags` is a function that returns an array of tags.

Like this, `tags` will just become a string `"getTags(that.id)"`. If I put it in an expression like;

```
<my-directive ng-repeat="that in a" tags="{{getTags(that.id)}}"></my-directive>
```

`tags` will still be a string. But it will look like `"['new', 'owner']"` - but still a string. How do I pass the array?

Answer (score 3):

You need to parse the variable:

```
scope.tags = scope.$eval(scope.tags);
```

Comment: I can't seem to override the `scope.tags` variable by doing like this?

Comment: Try in a different variable then.

Comment: Hello i had the same problem and using $eval solved it, can you please explain me why i should use $eval and if there is a better way to achieve the same thing without the use of $eval?